# How do I detect what browser features I'm using?

Tags: jquery, modernizr, browser-feature-detection

I have an existing code base that uses the latest jQuery and jQuery-ui along with some other plugins. I've been asked to detect browsers that do not support the features being used in this code base and warn the user that their browser is not fully supported and suggest they upgrade/switch browsers.

It appears that the appropriate tool for this task is something like Modernizr. The problem is, without going through each line of code myself I don't really know which features are, or are not being used. So I don't know how to build my test cases to make sure that a given browser is supported.

Is there a script or tool I can use to help determine which features I'm currently using? Or some set of existing checks I can use to make this easier?

Comment: Show a message to users of older versions of IE that they should upgrade, and leave it at that, as jQuery will work fine in other browsers and IE9 and up (and below as well).

Comment: The problem is there are other plugins that are not jQuery which may or may not have their own feature sets that need to be included.

Answer (score 0):

Can I suggest a different approach?

Define a subset of browsers that your site/application is optimized for let's say Chrome and Safari, then for older versions of IE's and Firefox or Operas, display a message informing that the application/site is not optimized for the users browser and depending on the browser perform your suggestions.

If this is not a solution, then it seems to me that for each third-party plugin, you will have to find a way to acquire dynamically their supported browsers, if the plugin providers don't have such APIs, you can write your own files like plugin_name.browser containing something ie7:nok, opera:nok ... of course you will have to test the plugins in the common browsers in the web like FF, Opera, Chrome, IE, Safari.

Hope this help,

Sometime the better solution is the simpler.

Regards.